# When i connect usb camera with android device then get error in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, usbserial, usb-camera

```
[UsbDevice: /dev/bus/usb/002/002, 547-137b USB2.0 Camera, TP̜USB2.0 Cam null]
I/flutter (32260): null
E/flutter (32260): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(UsbSerialPortAdapter, Not an Serial device., null, null)
E/flutter (32260): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
E/flutter (32260): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
E/flutter (32260): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32260): #2      UsbSerial.createFromDeviceId (package:usb_serial/usb_serial.dart:432:33)
E/flutter (32260): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32260): #3      UsbDevice.create (package:usb_serial/usb_serial.dart:332:13)
E/flutter (32260): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32260): #4      _MainPageState.checkUSB (package:quasmo/Pages/main_screen.dart:59:12)
E/flutter (32260): <asynchronous suspension>
```